# Tracking number patterns

Tags: tracking, fedex, ups

Is there any place to get patterns for shipping tracking numbers for all shipping companies like UPS,FedEX, DHL, AirBorne, USPS ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fedex:
XXXXXXXXXXXX (12 numbers)

DHL:

- International Air Freight Shipments -
  7 digit HAWB number 1234567
- International Ocean Shipments - 9
  character HBL number SEA123456
- U.S. Domestic Shipments* – 3
  character origin code and HAWB
  number, which can be up to 10 digits
  in length. SEA1234567

[DHL Tracking Number Information Page](http://www.us.danzas.com/frameset.cgi?winLocation=http://www.us.danzas.com/help/tandt.html)

Canadian Postal Service:
[Canadian Postal Service Tracking Information Page](http://www.canadapost.ca/Personal/Help/UsingTrack.aspx#Tracking)

UPS:
Begins with 1Z

If it's UPS, Fedex or USPS, you can send the number into Google and get the type from the Google result.

Airborne is now DHL.

Answer (score 4):

Fedex: 12, 14, 15, 20, 22 digits are all valid tracking number

UPS: 1Z + 16 digits or begin with W,T,H + 10 digits

DHL: 10 digits ONLY (if u mention the express shipping, as DHL also have cargo, sea shipment etc)

usps: https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction!input.action

Notice that as far as i know, there is not a complete list there.

If anyone know the new tracking number format, please let me know too.

As I run a startup http://www.aftership.com which also need to detect the tracking number pattern.